# Reading CSV from std::ifstream in good time

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read x, y, z values from an `std::ifstream`. Here is the rough outline of how it works at the moment:

```
struct Vec3 {

    Vec3(const double x, const double y, const double z) :
        x(x), y(y), z(z)
    {}

    double x, y, z;
}

std::vector<Vec3> readFile(std::ifstream& is) {
    std::vector<Vec3> retval;
    std::string str;
    while (std::getline(is, str)) {
        std::vector<std::string> strings;
        std::stringstream ss(str);
        for (std::string entry; std::getline(ss, entry, ','); ) {
            strings.push_back(entry);
        }
        const auto x = std::stof(strings[0]);
        const auto y = std::stof(strings[1]);
        const auto z = std::stof(strings[2]);
        retval.emplace_back(x, y, z);
    }
    return retval;
}
```

This works reasonably well, but the amount of `string` involved (and the relative simplicity of the corresponding file-writing function which uses `sprintf_s` to excellent effect) makes me wonder if theres a faster way to read from `ifstream` and construct the `std::vector<Vec3>`. Furthermore, using `std::getline` *twice*, as well as constructing a `std::stringstream` every time makes me think this code has some unnecessary overhead. I've tried a couple of approaches such as using the `ifstream`'s `operator>>` but this either yields no real improvement or begins mangling the output.

The guarantees we can make are that the format of each line is of three numbers with a comma separator.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you:

```
double x, y, z;
char c; // comma
while (is >> x >> c >> y >> c >> z) {
  retval.emplace_back(x, y, z);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work completely for me, unfortunately... no noticeable difference in run time, although the simpler code is certainly a plus. Something that avoids use of `operator>>` would be great, but I have no idea how realistic that actually is.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a combination that worked better than the original implementation posted in the question, inspired in good part by @0x499602D2 's answer.

```
std::vector<Vec3> readFile(std::ifstream& is) {
    double x, y, z;
    std::vector<Vec3> retval;
    std::string str;
    while (std::getline(is, str)) {
        sscanf_s(str.c_str(), "%lg%*c%lg%*c%lg", &x, &y, &z);
        retval.emplace_back(x, y, z);
    }
    return retval;
}
```

Gutting the `while` loop helped immensely. As for the weird sscanf format, the `%lg` prevents conversion errors between `float` and `double` (we are reading and storing to `double`) and the `%*c` instructs recognition of a character but not storing it, thus effectively skipping over the comma. It looks like code golf, but it works (or at least seems to).